# How to authorize user in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, refactoring

We have auth microservice and an admin panel based on laravel. We login user by calling auth api and returning user id and token. How I could make user as authorized in laravel 5.3? I did not found any information googling.

```
$request = Request();

$authorize = new Authorize();
$response = $authorize->logIn($request->all());

if ($response->status == 'success') {
    $user = new User();
    $userResponse = $user->getUser($response->data->id);
    Session::put('userId', $response->data->id);
    Session::put('userToken', $response->data->token);
    Session::put('userData', $userResponse);

    if ($request->input('save_login')) {
        Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('savedLogin', $request->input('login'), 129600, null, null, false, false));
    } else {
         Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('savedLogin'));
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: what virstion you are using laravel

Comment: Auth::loginUsingId(1); login using user id

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta I wrote in post

Comment: @JigneshJoisar can you write some documentation please?

Answer (score 4):

You can manually log in the `user` with either the `id` or the User Instance.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users):

**Authenticate A User Instance**

> If you need to log an existing user instance into your application,
>   you may call the login method with the user instance. The given object
>   must be an implementation of the 
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract. Of course, the
>   App\User model included with Laravel already implements this
>   interface:

```
Auth::login($user);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::login($user, true);
```

**Authenticate A User By ID**

> To log a user into the application by their ID, you may use the
>   loginUsingId method. This method accepts the primary key of the user
>   you wish to authenticate:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);
```